# Create circular loading whit tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I was wondering how to make a circular loading animation using tkinter.

Something like this:

[image]

But tehre is nothing on internet about this in python

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Search this site for `[tkinter] animated gif` and you'll find several questions with answers.